# LiClipse -- Can't add python3 interpreter from cygwin

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, cygwin, pydev

I'm running LiClipse on windows 7, 64bit.

When I go to preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter->New, and try to add the interpreter located at C:\cygwin\bin\python3.2m.exe. I see an error `Unable to get info on the interpreter... Reason: See error log for details.`

In the log:

```
No output was in the standard output when
trying to create the interpreter info for: C:\cygwin\bin\python3.2m.exe
The error output contains:
>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 1.2.0\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.8.0.201409251617\pysrc\interpreterInfo.py", line 167, in <module>
    if sys.platform == "cygwin" and not executable.endswith('.exe'):
TypeError: endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
<<
```

This looks like a python2 vs python3 issue, but I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, is pydev compatible with 3.2? I intend to be developing 3.x code so I do need to use a python3 interpreter.

**Edit:** If I choose `C:\cygwin\bin\python2.7.exe` instead, It works. There is definitely something wonky with Python3 here.

PyDev version: 3.8.0.201409251617

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the output of the call to `ctypes.cdll.cygwin1.cygwin_conv_path` in [interpreterInfo.py](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/pysrc/interpreterInfo.py#L60) is bytes string.
No problem in python2 as all other string declarations are also bytes strings (because without the `u''` prefix), but in python3, default is unicode string, so the script is trying to find if a bytes string ends with a unicode string which is not good.

To fix it, you need to convert the input of the `nativePath` into bytes string (or it will be just `/` in the C function) and then the output into unicode string.
I proposed a pull request for this on GitHub: [#133](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/pull/133).